# jQuery way of applying the same function to different ID objects based on which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to bodge together a tool that takes an excel table input, creates a table, adds a button to each table row, and has that button trigger a timer. so far I have managed to scrape together the functionality that creates the table, i've managed to apply different ID's to each dynamically created span element holding the timer value, and have found a basic setInterval() function with the timer functionality. I am having trouble getting the timer function to apply to each span element when the adjacent startTimer button is clicked. Currently, all buttons have the same class. I am assuming the way to go about it is with assigning unique ID's for each button and a for loop that iterates over each span ID, but at this point i am pretty lost. To understand how the table creating works here you can just put in a couple of words on separate lines in the text area.

Apologies for all the bad coding practices in the attached JS fiddle, at this point i think its fairly obviously i am not any good at this.

```js
    function generateTable() {
    var data = $('textarea[name=excel_data]').val();
    console.log(data);
var rows = data.split("\n");

var table = $('<table id="theTable" />');

for(var y in rows) {
    var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
    var row = $('<tr class="tableRow" />');
    for(var x in cells) {
        row.append('<td>'+cells[x]+'</td>');
    }
    table.append(row);    
}   
// Insert into DOM
$('#excel_table').html(table);
$('#excel_table tr').each(function()
{   
    $(this).append('<td> <input type="button" class="startClock" value="start timer"/><span>20</span> </td>');
    
});
 
$('#excel_table span').each(
  function(index){
     $(this).attr('id','count'+index)  
    });



$(".startClock").click( function(){
   let counter = 20;
   setInterval(function() {
   let  ind=0
    var numRows = $('.tableRow').length;
     for(i=0;i<=numRows;i++){
      ind=i
     };
     counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
         span = document.getElementById('count0')
         span.innerHTML = counter +"seconds";
      }
      if (counter === 0) {
         document.getElementById('count0').innerHTML='available';
         clearInterval(counter);
       }
     }, 1000);
});

}
```

```css
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
border:1px solid #000000;
}

table td{
border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Paste excel data here:</p>
    <textarea name="excel_data" style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:generateTable()" value="Genereate Table"/>
     <input type="button" id='listNum' value="Genereate"/>
<br><br>
    <p><span id='howMany'></span>Table data will appear below</p>
<hr>
<div id="excel_table"></div>
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v40wn25u/)

Comment: There's no need for unique IDs; you can use something like `$(this).closest('tr').find('td.timer')` to go up from the button to the row, then back down to the timer cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.next()` to walk from the `button` to `span`

```js
function generateTable() {
  var data = $('textarea[name=excel_data]').val();
  //console.log(data);
  var rows = data.split('\n');

  var table = $('<table id="theTable" />');

  for (var y in rows) {
    var cells = rows[y].split('\t');
    var row = $('<tr class="tableRow" />');
    for (var x in cells) {
      row.append('<td>' + cells[x] + '</td>');
    }
    table.append(row);
  }
  // Insert into DOM
  $('#excel_table').html(table);
  $('#excel_table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).append(
      '<td> <input type="button" class="startClock" value="start timer"/><span>20</span> </td>'
    );
  });

  $('#excel_table span').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'count' + index);
  });

  $('.startClock').click(function() {
    let counter = 20;
    let span = $(this).next();
    setInterval(function() {
      counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
        span.html(counter + ' seconds');
      }
      if (counter === 0) {
        span.html('available');
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px;
}
span{
margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Paste excel data here:</p>
<textarea name="excel_data" style="width: 250px; height: 150px"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:generateTable()" value="Genereate Table" />
<input type="button" id="listNum" value="Genereate" />
<br /><br />
<p><span id="howMany"></span>Table data will appear below</p>
<hr />
<div id="excel_table"></div>
```